# Call a method from the main activity class to a non activity class java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, class, methods

Good day guys,
I have a method at my MainActivity java that will mark the places at the googlemap fragment, but when I call that method from a non activity class it gives me an error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare()

My mainActivity method that can make a marker is

```
public void addMarkers(Double lat, Double lng, String name){
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .title(name)
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
}
```

and my non Activity class that is calling the method is

```
private int parseDataTag(){
    try {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo = null;

        AdvanceSearch advanceSearch = new AdvanceSearch(); //MainActivity class

        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

            int id = jo.getInt("id");
            String name = jo.getString("name");
            String lat = jo.getString("latitude");
            String lng = jo.getString("longtitude");
            advanceSearch.addMarkers(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng), name);
        }

        return 1;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are blocking your mainthread UI thread..that's why

Comment: what do you mean sir Akshay? sorry beginner here :)

Comment: `AdvanceSearch advanceSearch = new AdvanceSearch();` - this will give you a completely standalone instance of your "MainActivity". Its UI won't ever be displayed, so adding markers is quite useless. If you want to show an `Activity` in `android`, use something like `startActivity(new Intent(myCurrentContext, MyNewActivity.class));` See also Shivam Rawat's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an object of an activity like a normal Java class because activities have to go through the activity lifecycle to attain a valid context.

Instead you could create an interface listener that would help you communicate back to your activity.

You can find out how to do this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score -1):

You should call your method inside your activity using the context that you have.

```
 ((MainActivity) context).yourMethod();
```

Comment: This is too abstract. Please explain exactly how it will help.